# c# move to next tab in a tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl, with 5 TabPages, is there any way I can go through every tab pragmatically? I want to be able to see on what tab the user is, and after he/she clicks a button, the next tab will become available, automatically, so they can write something in that page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply change the selected index:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = (tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1 < tabControl1.TabCount) ?
                             tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1 : tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
```

In my example above, the `SelectedIndex` is increased based on the presently selected index -- if there is an additional tab to change to.

Comment: this is not the default tab behavior. You should replace the last `tabControl1.SelectedIndex` by `0`...

Answer (score 1):

If we're speaking about WinForms TabControl, there is a property `SelectedTab`

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the next tab would be:

```
  tabControl.SelectedIndex = 
    (tabControl.SelectedIndex + 1) % tabControl.TabCount;
```

You can get the current Tab with

```
tabControl.SelectedTab
```

Answer (score -1):

myTabs.SelectedTab = myTabs.TabPages["yourTABName"];
will do that easily.